# How can I iterate through an XML to create an Xpath in soapUI?

Tags: xpath, groovy, soapui, loops

I'm trying to set up a Load Test in soapUI for my API with a series of AMF Requests, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to make a property transfer with an XML response like this:

```
<flex.messaging.io.amf.ASObject serialization="custom">
  <unserializable-parents/>
  <map>
    <default>
      <loadFactor>0.75</loadFactor>
      <threshold>48</threshold>
    </default>
    <int>64</int>
    <int>28</int>
    <string>key</string>
    <boolean>value</boolean>
    <string>key</string>
    <boolean>value</boolean>
    <string>key</string>
    <string>value</string>
    <string>key</string>
    <boolean>value</boolean>
    <string>key</string>
    <null/>
    <string>key</string>
    <null/>
    <string>key</string>
    <null/>
    <string>key</string>
    <null/>
    <string>key</string>
    <null/>
    <string>key</string>
    <null/>
    <string>key</string>
    <boolean>value</boolean>
    <string>key</string>
    <boolean>value</boolean>
    <string>key</string>
    <null/>
    <string>key</string>
    <string>value</string>
    <string>key</string>
    <string>value</string>
    <string>key</string>
    <object-array/>
    <string>key</string>
    <flex.messaging.io.amf.ASObject serialization="custom">
      <unserializable-parents/>
      <map>
        <default>
          <loadFactor>0.75</loadFactor>
          <threshold>12</threshold>
        </default>
        <int>16</int>
        <int>3</int>
        <string>key</string>
        <boolean>value</boolean>
        <string>key</string>
        <boolean>value</boolean>
        <string>key</string>
        <boolean>value</boolean>
      </map>
      <flex.messaging.io.amf.ASObject>
        <default>
          <inHashCode>false</inHashCode>
          <inToString>false</inToString>
          <namedType>package/class</namedType>
        </default>
      </flex.messaging.io.amf.ASObject>
    </flex.messaging.io.amf.ASObject>
    <string>key</string>
    <string>value</string>
    <string>key</string>
    <boolean>value</boolean>
    <string>key</string>
    <string>value</string>
    <string>key</string>
    <flex.messaging.io.amf.ASObject serialization="custom">
      <unserializable-parents/>
      <map>
        <default>
          <loadFactor>0.75</loadFactor>
          <threshold>12</threshold>
        </default>
        <int>16</int>
        <int>5</int>
        <string>key</string>
        <boolean>value</boolean>
        <string>key</string>
        <boolean>value</boolean>
        <string>key</string>
        <boolean>value</boolean>
        <string>key</string>
        <boolean>value</boolean>
        <string>key</string>
        <boolean>value</boolean>
      </map>
      <flex.messaging.io.amf.ASObject>
        <default>
          <inHashCode>false</inHashCode>
          <inToString>false</inToString>
          <namedType>package/class</namedType>
        </default>
      </flex.messaging.io.amf.ASObject>
    </flex.messaging.io.amf.ASObject>
    <string>guid</string>
    <string>818f40db-c217-46ed-a6a2-7c830d894a95</string>
    <string>key</string>
    <string>value</string>
    <string>key</string>
    <null/>
    <string>key</string>
    <string>value</string>
    <string>key</string>
    <string>value</string>
    <string>key</string>
    <null/>
    <string>key</string>
    <null/>
  </map>
  <flex.messaging.io.amf.ASObject>
    <default>
      <inHashCode>false</inHashCode>
      <inToString>false</inToString>
      <namedType>package/class</namedType>
    </default>
  </flex.messaging.io.amf.ASObject>
</flex.messaging.io.amf.ASObject>
```

As I'm not using soapUI Pro, I don't have access to the xpath wizard. Is there a way to access this node with a Property transfer or a Groovy Script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access those two like so using XmlSlurper:

```
def src = '''<flex.messaging.io.amf.ASObject serialization="custom">
            |  <unserializable-parents/>
            |  <map>
            |    <default>
            |      <loadFactor>1.00</loadFactor>
            |      <threshold>50</threshold>
            |    </default>
            |    <string>Not what I need</string>
            |    <string>Not what I need</string>
            |    <string>Not what I need</string>
            |    <string>Not what I need</string>
            |    <string>Not what I need</string>
            |    <object-array/>
            |    <string>Not what I need</string>
            |    <string>This is the KEY I'm looking for</string>
            |    <string>This is the VALUE I need to pass to the next test step</string>
            |    <string>Not what I need</string>
            |    <string>Not what I need</string>
            |    <string>Not what I need</string>
            |    <null/>
            |    <string>Not what I need</string>
            |    <string>Not what I need</string>
            |    <string>Not what I need</string>
            |    <string>Not what I need</string>
            |    <string>Not what I need</string>
            |    <null/>
            |    <string>Not what I need</string>
            |    <null/>
            |  </map>
            |</flex.messaging.io.amf.ASObject>'''.stripMargin()

def aso = new XmlSlurper().parseText( src )

def (key,value) = aso.map.string[6..7]*.text()

println "  key = $key"
println "value = $value"
```

This feels a bit 'hard-coded', but I cannot see how those values can be located programatically :-(

---

#### Edit

Given the new XML you posted, this seems to work in this instance:

```
println aso.map.children()[ 3..-1 ]    // Strip out the initial default and ints
       .collate( 2 )                   // Group the key/value pairs
       .findAll { 
         it[ 0 ].text() == 'guid'      // find all that have 'guid' as element 0
       }
       .collectEntries { it*.text() }  // convert this into a map
```

And prints:

```
[guid:818f40db-c217-46ed-a6a2-7c830d894a95]
```

However, a more thorough depthFirst algorithm might be a more solid way of scanning all possible inputs (I don't know ASObject serialization, so I don't know if this just works for this instance)

---

#### Edit 2

As you are stuck with a version of Groovy with no `collate` method (1.8.6), you can do something like this using a traditional `for` loop:

```
def aso = new XmlSlurper().parseText( src ).map.children()
String guid = null
for( i = 3 ; i < aso.size() ; i += 2 ) {
  if( aso[ i ] == 'guid' ) {
    guid = aso[ i + 1 ]
    break
  }
}
println guid
```

Comment: Well, let me be more specific. The Key I'm looking for will always be "guid", then the next string after that is the value that I need to use in the next test step. So it seems like I need to:

Comment: 1. Resference the response from step one in the script from step two.
2. iterate through the response xml looking for "guid"
3. assign the string after "guid" to a variable to use in a property expansion.

Does that sound correct?

Comment: @JonathanLoiselle Is the XML you posted correct?  I would have expected an even number of key/value entries, but this seems to have `GUID` in an odd position, rather than that of a key...

Comment: No, I'm sorry, in my effort to desensitize the content, I did not in fact pay attention to the key/value pair numbers. I just expected the solution to be an iterative search rather than a hard coded position, but that should work as well...I don't believe the position will ever change in the response. But as you can see in my edit, the actual response is much longer

Comment: ${Search Request#Response#//ns1:Item[1]/n1:Author[1]/text()}

Which would first get the "Response" property of the "Search Request" step and then select the value of the first Items' first Author element. Note that the namespace prefix must match those used in the response message, otherwise the expansion will fail.

Comment: ^^^^ This looks like it might work as well...as long as I reference the correct string tag number?

Comment: @JonathanLoiselle Added a bit of code that seems to work in the instance you supplied ;-)

Comment: its hanging up on the collate method.I'm getting this error:
No signature of method: java.util.SubList.collate() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.Integer) values: [2]

if I remove the .collate and .collectEntires from the code i can get it to assign [guid] to the appropriate property.

Comment: Ahhhhh... Must be an old version of groovy

Comment: However your first answer converted to support only one value(def temp = aso.map.string[27]*.text() ) works as long as I don't set any additional variables in the first step as this would change the number of tags of the value 'string'. Ideally I would like to get your second method to work as its more dynamic.

Comment: I'll post a version that doesn't use collate tomorrow when I can get to a computer :-)

Comment: @JonathanLoiselle Added a new **Edit2** section to the answer ;-)

Comment: Thanks! Works great, now I just have to figure out how to reference the XML response from AMF request One in AMF request Two without a property transfer. But I've got a seperate thread for that :)